# Deploying Ruby on Rails application to Railway: Crashed error with PostgreSQL configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, deployment, railway

I'm using Rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.0.2.

The first time I tried to deploy, I understood that I needed to start by using Redis and PostgreSQL. In one of the videos on Youtube, I learned that I should create a Procfile with the command line `web: rake db:migrate && bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p {PORT: -3000}`. After that, I put the application on GitHub and then selected the application on Railway to deploy it. Then, I received an error that apparently got resolved when I changed `{PORT: -3000}` to `PORT`, as suggested in the comments of one of the videos. I also saw that I should create a railway.json file with the following configuration:

```
{
"$schema": "https://railway.app/railway.schema.json",
"build": {
"builder": "NIXPACKS"
},
"deploy": {
"restartPolicyType": "ON_FAILURE",
"restartPolicyMaxRetries": 10
}
}
```

After that, the error message was different this time: "crashed". Then, while watching another video, I learned that I should add some parameters to the configurations on the Railway website, specifically under "variables > RAW Editor". Some of the parameters were:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${{ PGUSER }}:{{ PGPASSWORD }}@${{ PGHOST }}:${{ PGPORT }}/${{ PGDATABASE }}
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PGDATABASE=railway
PGHOST=containers-us-west-77.railway.app
PGPASSWORD=*********
PGPORT=******
PGUSER=postgres
PORT=3000
RACK_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=***********
RAILS_MAX_THREADS=5
REDIS_URL=*********
```

However, I received the "Crashed" error again, and in the data log, the error was `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): postgresql://postgres:{{ PGPASSWORD }}@containers-us` (...).

Before posting this question here, I searched for any similar ones and found the post at [Deploying Ruby on Rails apps to Railway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117471/deploying-ruby-on-rails-apps-to-railway). But, the answer to that post states all the files should have this permission set: `-rwxr-xr-x`, and mine already are.

Looking at the PGPASSWORD in the RAW Editor ENV and PGPASSWORD in Postgres connect, they are the same. My main question is: In the Gemfile, the database for Active Record is set as "gem 'sqlite3', '1.4'". Does that have something to do with it? Should I be using PostgreSQL instead?

Comment: Yes you need to use the pg gem to use a Postgres database

Comment: thankss, I used the postgres gem, and I can use the application locally with rails s, but when I try to deploy it, I receive the crash error again. This time, I think it may be a problem with the database.yml file, and I am researching about it.